# bootstrap class.active not working in Angular 8

Tags: angular

[class.active] is not working in my code some time before it is working that time i was using angular and old version Bootstrap but now upgrade on angular 8 and bootstrap 4.2.1 it is not working code is here

```
<a *ngFor="let cat of categoryArray;let i=index;"
                routerLink="/" 
                [queryParams]="{category: cat.CategoryId}"
                class="list-group-item list-group-item-action" 
                [class.active]= "category === cat.CategoryId"   
                (click)="fileUploadComponent.Save()"
                >               
                  {{cat.Name}}
              </a>
```

problem is, condition of following line always false but in fact it should not.

```
[class.active]= "category === cat.CategoryId"
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
[attr.routerLinkActive]="category === cat.CategoryId ? 'active: null"
```

Comment: Sorry above both are not working any other solution

Comment: actually category  is always null

Answer (score 0):

```
[ngClass]="{'active': category == cat.CategoryId}"
```

Comment: Share a stackbiltz